# How to access a particular Hasura console using admin-secret

Tags: flutter, graphql, hasura

I have been assigned a task which requires me to use the graphql_flutter package to develop a news API. I have been provided with an Authorization token as such:

"x-hasura-admin-secret": "*****************************************************"

According to what I have been given here it clearly implies that I have to use Hasura Graphql to make my API with flutter. Can anyone please guide me on how I can use this "x-hasura-admin-secret" to access the console which will then take me to that particular endpoint that they want me to fetch my data from?

Please do note that I have gone through numerous documentations of official sites, github and other websites. Also this is the first time I am working with hasura or Graphql hence it would really be of help if you can outline the steps I should follow here rather than directing me towards a documentation or tutorial as I have already done that, just didn't get a solution that fits my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The admin secret by itself is not useful to you if you don't know the endpoint that it is associated with. It is impossible for us to help you figure that out. You need to ask them for the associated endpoint and then when you navigate to it in your browser you will be prompted for the admin secret like below:

[image: hasura console]

Once you're inside, you can easily retrieve the actual GraphQL endpoint that you'll be sending requests against from your application by looking in the top left corner:

[image: graphql endpoint]